# R, dplyr, Conditionally change values in multiple columns based on one conditional column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("a" = 1:5, "b" = 2:6, "c" = 3:7, "d" = c(NA,1,1,0,0))
```

How can I change values in columns `a`, `b`, and `c` to `NA` if values in column `d` are either `NA` or `0`? I can get it to work easily for individual columns, e.g., `df[,3][df$d==0|is.na(df$d)] <- NA`, but I'm having trouble getting something to work across multiple columns. I'd very much appreciate solutions in base R or `dplyr`. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
df[is.na(df$d) | df$d == 0, cols] <- NA
df
#   a  b  c  d
#1 NA NA NA NA
#2  2  3  4  1
#3  3  4  5  1
#4 NA NA NA  0
#5 NA NA NA  0
```

Or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(ifelse(is.na(d) | d == 0, NA, .)))
#   a  b  c  d
#1 NA NA NA NA
#2  2  3  4  1
#3  3  4  5  1
#4 NA NA NA  0
#5 NA NA NA  0
```

Comment: Or `data.table` to complete the trinity - `df[is.na(d) | d == 0, c("a","b","c") := NA]`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of simultaneously sub-setting rows and columns.